# Split a column in two in r

Tags: r, stringr

My df looks like this :

```
Time
Week End 07-01-10
Week End 07-02-10
```

I want it as

```
Column        Time
Week End   07-01-10
Week End   07-02-10
```

I googled package `stringr` would be useful but I am unable to use it correctly since there are two spaces.

Comment: Your pasted df looks like it only has one space. What code have you tried?

Comment: There are two spaces; one after **Week** and the other after **End**. I did not try any code as of now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extract` from `tidyr` package where you can specify regular expressions to split the column:

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, Time, into = c("Column", "Time"), "(.*)\\s(\\S+)")
#     Column     Time
# 1 Week End 07-01-10
# 2 Week End 07-02-10
```

Use `(.*)\\s(\\S+)` to capture two groups and split on the space which is followed by a group which contains no space `\\S+`.

If you want to use `stringr` package, you can use `str_match` function with similar functionality:

```
stringr::str_match(df$Time, "(.*)\\s(\\S+)")[, 2:3]
#      [,1]       [,2]      
# [1,] "Week End" "07-01-10"
# [2,] "Week End" "07-02-10"
```

`strsplit` also works if you specify the space to be the one before the digit, here `?=` stands for look ahead and `\\d` is a abbreviation for digits and is equivalent to `[0-9]`:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$Time, "\\s(?=\\d)", perl = T))
#      [,1]       [,2]      
# [1,] "Week End" "07-01-10"
# [2,] "Week End" "07-02-10"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Psidom, but what do I need to do if there are more columns in the dataframe and I want to create a dataframe with just a change to this column ?

Comment: Use the first version, `extract` from tidyr package, it should leave other columns untouched.

Comment: It throws the following error **Error: could not find function "extract"**

Comment: You need to load the `tidyr` package. Updated the answer to make it more obvious. And also try to reinstall your tidyr package, it might be your package is too old.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` from `base R`.  No packages needed

```
read.table(text=sub("\\s+(\\S+)$", ",\\1", df1$Time), header=FALSE, 
     col.names = c("Column", "Time"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",")
#    Column     Time
#1 Week End 07-01-10
#2 Week End 07-02-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base-R solution.

```
df <- data.frame(c("Week End 07-01-10", "Week End 07-02-10"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df) <- "Time"

# Assuming all columns end with (time?) in the same format.
df$Column <- substring(df$Time, 0, nchar(df$Time)-9)
df$Time <- substring(df$Time, nchar(df$Time)-8, nchar(df$Time))
df <- df[, c(2,1)]; df # Changing column order
```